# Algorithm Optimization Troubles: N x N Matrix Permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, combinatorics

Problem: Determine all possible permutations of a n x n binary matrix.

Conditions: Each row and column contains t 1's; The Main diagonal only     contains zeros; Do not actually construct the matrices.

Example: n = 3, t = 2

```
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

I've managed a recursive solution that iterates over all possible permutations in c++.

Its been hinted by our professor that the optimization for this algorithm lies in not actually iterating over possible solutions to the left of the diagonal but I just cant get it.

In this code the "state vector" represents the number of ones yet to be assigned int the corresponding column, and the "puck" represents the current row and index of diagonal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// Global Variables
int n = 4;      // Length and height of matrix
int t = 1;  // Number of 1's in each row and column

int numSolutions(int state_vector[], int puck)
{
    int row[n];     // holds current row of matrix
    int total = 0;  // holds current number of permutations

    // Populate row with, n-t = 0, last t elements = 1
    // for n = 6, t = 2; (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    // next_permutation() will be used to iterate over all permutations
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(i < n-t)
            row[i] = 0;
        else
            row[i] = 1;
    }


    do
    {
        bool working = true;
        if(row[puck] == 0) // Test: is the diagonal element 0?
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if( (state_vector[i] - row[i]) < 0) // Test: does the current row have positions available to hold a 1?
                {
                    working = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            working = false;
        }

        // If the diagonal = 0, and there are positions able to hold a 1
        if(working)
        {
            int state_vector_copy[n];       //Holds copy of stat_vector

            // Copy state_vector
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                state_vector_copy[i] = state_vector[i] - row[i];
            }

            if( puck == (n-1) )     // Test: On last row of martrix?
            {
                total++;            // Solution found, increment total
            }
            else
            {
                total += numSolutions(state_vector_copy, puck+1); // Recursive call to next row
            }
        }
    }while(next_permutation(row, row+n));

    return total;

}

// Pass off function
int numSolutions(int length)
{
    int state_vector[length];

    // Populate state_vector with values of t,   
    // In a n = 6 t = 2 example
    // (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        state_vector[i] = t;
    }

    return numSolutions(state_vector, 0);
}

int main()
{

   cout << "Solution: " << numSolutions(n);
}
```

My idea was once I've iterated over all of the positions to the right of the "puck" I simply need to determine positions available to the left of the "puck" and compute (positions choose t) to get the remaining permutations.

However, I'm either wrong, or have failed to implement it...or both.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: So the actual problem is to determine **the number of** all possible permutations of a n x n binary matrix, not permutations themselves? Your problem statement is misleading.

Comment: Yes, please post a nontrivial worked example.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830930/possible-nxn-matrices-t-1s-in-each-row-and-column-none-in-diagonal